# ARP timeout in broadcast message

Tags: linux, ip, tcp, arp

Suppose i have source host H1(10.1.1.2/24) who wants to communicate to host H2(10.1.1.3/24). Since both hosts are in same subnet H1 sends a ARP broadcast. H2 replies to this broadcast and finally H1 gets H2 MAC address. Consequently communication establishes.

Now if H2 is down, H1 is not going to receive ARP reply from H2. So for what duration H1 will wait for ARP reply? RFC 826 does not talk about any such timer.

I found in some forum that it is 5 to 30 seconds. Is it correct?

Regards,
Sudhansu

Answer (score 3):

In your description you miss at least one thing. ARP reply is cached as ARP entry for a while. So H1 will send some traffic to blackhole after H2 is down. This period of time is selected as **random** number between `base_reachable_time/2` and `3*base_reachable_time/2`. (Random is used to distribute request from different devices in time). By default base_reachable_time is 30 seconds.

After this random time elapsed H1 tries to update ARP entry. Update is performed by unicast message (send directly to H1 without any broadcasting to network) by sending ARP request with interval `retrans_time_ms` (1 second by default). If `ucast_solicit` (3 by default) tries failed than broadcast probe is performed.

If broadcast probe also failed (`mcast_solicit` tries with interval `retrans_time_ms`) then ARP entry is considered incomplete. During this check kernel can hold packet sending to the H2 in the ARP queue.

Summing up:

- 15-45 seconds elapsed before ARP entry revalidation
- (3+3)*1000 milliseconds elapsed after probe is started and before ARP entry considered not valid.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. Answer is convincing. Which standard shall i refer for " base_reachable_time"? Or is it proprietary to some OS.

Comment: This algorithm is described in Neighbour Discovery for IPv6 https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4861 (I don't know for who was first - linux implementation or this specification). Parameter there is BaseReachableTime.